# Set array values on class runtime (and set Attributes onto them)?

Tags: c#

I was unable to define what to name this problem, thus tried google and here, but cant find.

Is there any way to set array(or dictionary) members value on property level, and set attribute onto them? like this:

```
public class XYZ{

    private string[] x= new string[]{"smth", "smth"}; 
    x[0] { get; set; }

    [Receipt(order=2, name="warranty")]
    x[1] { get; set; }
    ....

}
```

So, mainly I have to questions to be frank:

1) Is that possible to set attributes onto array members?

2) Is that possible (forget attribute) to assign value to array member in property level (not within method), like this?:

```
public class XYZ{

     private string[] x= new string[2](); 
     x[0] = "smth";  

}
```

Comment: You mean something like that?: 
private string[] x = {"smth", "smth"};
I didn't really understand the example.

Comment: @GiladReich no, i dont mean that, thanks

Comment: I think the short answer is no. You are trying to set an attribute on a member of an array? I don't think that's gonna work. What exactly are you trying to achieve with this structure?

Comment: @GiladReich question updated

Comment: @MattBurland question updated - yes, i want to set attribute on a member of an array.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is no. Attributes are for metadata, and this looks like actual data. Probably you should have your array be an array of some class that contains the value (i.e. `smth`) and all the data you wanted to have in your `ReceiptAttribute`.

Comment: @MattBurland you could posted as answer. thanks!

Comment: Q1) No. Q2) No. If you explained better how you'd intend to use this (if it was possible) then people might be able to suggest an elegant solution that would achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is definitely ***no***. Attributes can only be added onto compile-time features such as **classes** and **methods**. Not onto runtime features such as object data.

Also your getter/setter syntax is very wrong, it can only be like this:

```
public int Month { get; set; }
```

So an *access modifier* (**public**; optional), followed by a *Type* (**int**), followed by the *name* (**Month**), and then the *get and/or set specification*.

Comment: Actually there are quite a lot of places [where attributes can be applyed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/attributes#how-to-restrict-attribute-usage)

Comment: Totally true, thanks, I never meant to be exhaustive.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it exactly the way you want, but you can get close:

```
public class XYZ
{
    private string[] x= new string[]{"smth", "smth"}; 

    [Receipt(order=1, name="warranty")]
    public string Receipt1 {get { return x[0];} set{x[0] = value;} }

    [Receipt(order=2, name="warranty")]
    public string Receipt2 {get { return x[1];} set{x[1] = value;} }

    //...  
}
```

Of course, the number of entries here are fixed, and you have to give these properties a real, meaningful name. You can't have a dynamic number of entries that changes while the program runs.

The one other thing you can look at is an [indexer property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/). With an indexer, you can only set your attribute *once* on the whole property, rather than individual elements, but it will allow the number of items to change at run time.

Comment: joel, thanks, but that's what i wanted to avoid (fixed names of properties), as i have bunch of dynamic arrays and wanted to setup them flexibly, without this way. however, thanks for help.

Comment: In that case, attributes are probably not what you want. Perhaps look into using Dictionaries, but the desire to do this typically indicates a poor design decision made much earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no. Attributes are for metadata, and this looks like actual data. Probably you should have your array be an array of some class that contains the value (i.e. smth) and all the data you wanted to have in your `ReceiptAttribute`.

So something like:

```
public class Receipt
{
    public string Value {get; set;}
    public int Order {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And then:

```
public class XYZ
{

    private Receipt[] x= new Receipt[]
    {
        new Receipt() { Value = "smth", Order = 1, Name = "warranty" },
        new Receipt() { Value = "smth", Order = 2, Name = "warranty" },
    }; 
}
```

And, obviously, when you want the value you'd do something like:

```
x[0].Value
```